# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o389.csv

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm new to pyspark. I'm running pyspark using databricks. My data is stored in Azure Data Lake Service.I'm trying to read csv file from ADLS to pyspark data frame. So I wrote following code

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext 
from pyspark import SparkFiles

df = sqlContext.read.csv(SparkFiles.get("dbfs:mycsv path in ADSL/Data.csv"), 
   header=True, inferSchema= True)
```

But I'm getting error message

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o389.csv.
```

Can you suggest me to rectify this error?

Answer (score 1):

The `SparkFiles` class is intended for accessing the files shipped as part of the Spark job.  If you just need access to the CSV file available on ADLS, then you just need to use `spark.read.csv`, like:

```py
df = spark.read.csv("dbfs:mycsv path in ADSL/Data.csv", 
  header=True, inferSchema=True)
```

it's better not to use `sqlContext`, it's kept for compatibility reasons.